# Build Systems (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

What exactly is the difference between the `default` and all `all` target rules? Is `all` only used for when pattern rules are used or can it be used for when explicit and implicit rules are used?

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by `default` and `all`.  By `default` are you referring to a target explicitly named `default` or simply the target that will be built if you just type `make` at the command prompt?  Can you provide an example `makefile`?

Comment: If you write the makefile you can use whatever target names for whatever you want. Make doesn't impose any restrictions.

Comment: "all" is a conventional name for a makefile target that builds all components of the project. But this is just a convention: `make` does not attribute special significance to that name.  "default" is *not* a conventional makefile target name, but `make` does have the sense of a *default target*, meaning the one that is built when the user runs `make` without requesting a specific target.  Part of the convention surrounding the "all" target name is that it should be positioned in the makefile so that it is the default target.  But again, that's merely a convention.